# Use snapped version of program inside bash script

Tags: shell-script, shell, snap

I have two version of a program install on my ubuntu 20.04 computer (`unison`). One is installed through `sudo apt install`, the other is a snap version. The program only works with the snap version.

When I run the program from the command line in a bash shell, it works fine (I assume it uses the snap version). When I run the identical command from inside a bash script, the program does not work. I assume that this is because it is using the non-snapped version. The command is

```
unison profile -sshargs '-i ~/.ssh/key' -auto
```

And the bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash
unison profile -sshargs '-i ~/.ssh/key' -auto
```

How can I get the same behaviour inside the bash script as in an interactive shell?

---

**Details:**

"Doesn't work" means I get this error message when running in the script:

> Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server:  expected
> "Unison 2.48\n" but received "Unison 2.51 with OCaml >=
> 4.01.2\n\000\000\000\000\017",  which differs at "Unison 2.5". This can happen because you have different versions of Unison installed on
> the client and server machines, or because your connection is failing
> and somebody is printing an error message, or because your remote
> login shell is printing something itself before starting Unison.

Comment: tilde `~` doesn't expand within quotes in a bash script

Comment: @αғsнιη that's probably not relevant here since the `'-i ~/.ssh/key'` is passed to `unison` so if it works when quoted from the command line, it should be the same.

Comment: maybe silly question but are you running script and command both with the same user?

Comment: @αғsнιη yes I run script and command as same user. In fact, I call the script from the same bash terminal where I also run the command.

Comment: OK, thanks, for now I cannot reproduce why it's not working within script; the errors says version mismatch but if that's true then it should not even work running directly in Terminal. maybe someone else can come with the reason and help you, I'm sorry.